# select first child node of root node in XML file using php

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm new to XML and have so far managed to obtain the root node of an XML using this in php...

```
function xmlRootNode($xmlfile){
    $xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($xmlfile));
    $xml = $xml->getName();
    echo $xml;
}
```

And what I now want to do is use that root node to find out the name of its child node. 
For example, a file with the below would output 'food' as the root using the above function. How would I now use that to return its childs name 'fruit'?

```
<food>
  <fruit>
    <type>apples</type>
  </fruit>
</food>
```

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is find out the child node name of the root node so I can then use it in another function that counts how many there are. Been googling and messing around with different ideas but think I'm missing a simple process somewhere so any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
/* get list of fruits under food */
$fruits = $xml->children();

/* or treat the $xml as array */
foreach ($xml as $fruit)
{
   /* your processing */
}
```

Additional, the below is redundant,

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($xmlfile));
```

switch it to

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile);
```

Comment: the $xml->children() is coming up with a non-object error. I tried converting it to an object but im still getting errors

Comment: hmmm... try this `$fruits = $xml->children(); foreach ($fruits as $fruit) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

```
// The following code block illustrates how you can get at the name of each child
$columnCDValues = array();
foreach ($simpleXMLElement->profile->children() as $child)
{
    $name = $child->getName();
    $value = $simpleXMLElement->profile->$name;         
    $columnCDValues[$child->getName()] = $value;
}
```