# Display most recent additions to XML file?

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I'm trying to display the latest additions to this NVD XML file:

```
http://static.nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/nvdcve-2.0-recent.xml
```

I can get all of them to list using the following code, but I'm only interested in displaying the most recent ten (from 2013 for the time being) and the XML file lists them in chronological order (starting in 2011).

```
<?php
$file= 'http://static.nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/nvdcve-2.0-recent.xml';
$xml = file_get_contents($file);
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$ns = $sxe->getNamespaces(true);

echo "<b>Latest Vulnerabilities:</b><p>";
foreach($sxe->entry as $entry)
{
    $vuln = $entry->children($ns['vuln']);
    $href = $vuln->references->reference->attributes()->href;
    echo "<a href=" . $href . ">" . $vuln->{'cve-id'} . "</a><br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307268/select-first-child-node-of-root-node-in-xml-file-using-php

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot manipulate the XML arrays directly, something like this should work for your needs:

```
$file= 'http://static.nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/nvdcve-2.0-recent.xml';
$xml = file_get_contents($file);
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$ns = $sxe->getNamespaces(true);

echo "<b>Latest Vulnerabilities:</b><p>";

$all = $sxe->entry;
$length = count($all);
$offset_start = $length - 10;

for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
{
    if($i >= $offset_start)
    {
        $entry = $all[$i];
        $vuln = $entry->children($ns['vuln']);
        $href = $vuln->references->reference->attributes()->href;
        echo "<a href=" . $href . ">" . $vuln->{'cve-id'} . "</a><br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: This great, but I'd like the most recent vulnerability (currently CVE-2013-5310) to be at the top of the list, followed the one before it (currently CVE-2013-5309) and so forth. My fault for not being clearer. I made the following code change and it worked, thanks for the help.        $count= count($all) - 1;

$offset = $count - 10;

while ($count >= $offset){

        $entry = $all[$count];
        $vuln = $entry->children($ns['vuln']);
        $href = $vuln->references->reference->attributes()->href;
        echo "<a href=" . $href . ">" . $vuln->{'cve-id'} . "</a><br>";

        $count--;
}